# how to fix react-timeago not updating on it's own

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react-timeago(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-timeago) package to show when an item in a component is last updated. I have  a card  component in which I render the  time  ago using a function, like this :

```
   //this is how I call the  render function in card.js file for the component
   <div className="Card-content-ctn">
    {renderHeading(props.resource.heading)}
    Last Edited {renderTimeAgo(props.resource.last_updated)}
    {renderDescription(props.resource.description)}
  </div>

 //this is how  the  render  method is implemented  in a  helper file(helpers.js)
 const renderTimeAgo = (last_updated) => {
 if (last_updated) return <TimeAgo date={last_updated} maxPeriod={5} live={true} />;
 };
```

Now the time go component does load and it displays the time that has passed since the item was last updated at but it doesn't update it. e.g if the  value of  `last_updated` is  a  `Date` object with time of 1 minute before. The component  says `Last updated 1 min ago` but it  will not change after  1 min to saying/showing `last  updated  2 mins ago`.

Here's how I am using this card component. I have another component for a page called `Home`. Inside this home component, I create a card component passing a  resource object that as prop, which gives the card component values to make the card. it's  like  this:

```
// Home.js
 let card_1 = (
<Card
  resource={resource}
  // media_type={resource.media_type}
  // media_url={resource.media_url}
  // heading={resource.heading}
  // last_updated={resource.last_updated}
  // description={resource.description}
  // is_favorite={resource.is_favorite}
  show_favorite={true}
  show_menu_trigger={true}
  handler={updateResource}
/>
);
 
 //return of home.js
 return <div className="Home-ctn">{card_1}</div>;
```

So during the whole development process, the timeago component would sometimes update the time correctly but sometimes it would. What I can tell you that I was doing the same thing, creating a `card` component in home.js with values passed in props(the card component's prop) and the `card` component's `timeago` component would work fine sometimes, and sometimes it wouldn't. It has been random all this time, I decided to work on other parts of the project and now it's the only part remaining(I'm pulling my hair with this one).

Some helpful insight: With the `timeago` component not updating on its own, whenever I do something that updates the state of the `home` component(which causes the home component to re-render), the values of the `timeago` component changes to whatever correct value is for the difference between current and time of `last_updated`.

Is there any way to detect when the 'react-timeago` changes the value for the time ago text, maybe I can handle that to change state and cause the home to re-render. But My actual question is that what am I doing wrong? Am I using the card component incorrectly? because  the timeago should be working fine(according to the API guidelines).

Really need help with this. Thank you in advance :D

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm having the exact same problem at the minute and I can't seem to get anywhere!

Comment: I imagine this issue is related to the following issue on GitHub: https://github.com/nmn/react-timeago/issues/154?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container